# Vlookup and Count String Occurrences in Separate Table R to new Column

Tags: r, count, dplyr, sqldf

I have two data frames. Below are samples but should be easily reproducible for illustration.

```
df1 <- data.frame(School = c("Omaha South", "Omaha Central", "Grand Island"), 
                  Enrollment = c(2166, 2051, 1982))
```

```
df2 <- data.frame('Away Score' = c(25, 57, 76), 
                  'Away Team' = c("Omaha South", "Omaha Central", "Grand Island"),
                  'Away Score' = c(52, 88, 69), 
                  'Away Team' = c("Omaha Central", "Grand Island", "Omaha South"),                 
                  Date = c("1/11/2020", "1/12/2020", "1/13/2020"),
                  Winner = c("Omaha Central", "Grand Island", "Grand Island"),
                  Loser = c("Omaha South", "Omaha Central", "Omaha South"))
```

My goal is to create a new column in df1 called "Wins" that looks up the school in df1 and then counts the number of times that school is listed in the "Winner" column of df2.

So want df1 to look like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(School = c("Omaha South", "Omaha Central", "Grand Island"), 
                  Enrollment = c(2166, 2051, 1982),
                  Wins = c(0, 1, 2))
```

I've tried a number of solutions to no avail, including sqldf. My latest attempt was the below but it gives me an error saying *no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "NULL"*

```
df$Wins %>%
     group_by(df2$Winner) %>%
     mutate(Count=n())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` and joins :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('School' = 'Winner')) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  count(School, name = "wins") %>%
  right_join(df1) %>%
  mutate(wins = replace(wins, is.na(wins), 0))
```

---

Using base R we calculate the frequency of wins using `table`, convert it into dataframe using `stack` and then `merge` to `df1`.

```
merge(df1, stack(table(factor(df2$Winner, levels = df1$School))), 
           by.x = 'School', by.y = "ind")
```

Comment: Is there a more strict pattern matching that can be used? Works fairly well but it's counting, for example, "Grand Island Central Catholic" as "Grand Island"

Comment: @JeffSwanson That should not happen. Can you show an example where it gives such matches to you?

Comment: I misspoke earlier (I can delete that comment). I'm getting all zeros in the Wins column instead of the proper count. Here is a gist that gets you to the full data frames I'm working with: https://gist.github.com/jeffgswanson/18d7fc4f7452a2e25680b1aed21b3861 or if you prefer I can update the question with the code.

Comment: @JeffSwanson You need to clean the school names. There are lot of `/r/n` in them. Try `df2 %>%
  mutate_all(~gsub('\r|\n', '', .)) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c('Winner' = 'School')) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  count(Winner, name = "wins") %>%
  right_join(df1, c('Winner' = 'School')) %>%
  mutate(wins = replace(wins, is.na(wins), 0))` this works for me for the dataset you shared.