# Match two dataframes with different column names and create new column with mean from the other

Tags: r, join, average, dplyr

I have two dataframes. The first one only lists each School/Team once, something like this:

```
classA <- data.frame(School=c("Omaha South", "Millard North", "Elkhorn"))
```

The other dataframe is a table of basketball scores throughout a season and you can a School/Team can be listed more than once in the same column:

```
scores <- data.frame('Away Score'=c(60,84,48,72),
                     'Away Team'=c("Omaha South", "Millard North", "Elkhorn","Elkhorn"),
                     'Home Score'=c(88,40,38,62),
                     'Home Team'=c("Elkhorn", "Omaha South", "Millard North","Omaha South"))
```

My goal is to create a new column called classA$'Away PPG' that averages all of the 'Away Scores' for each School in the first data frame. So as a result, for Elkhorn, the new classA column would be 60 (48+72)/2.

One of the places I'm getting stuck is that the two dfs have different column names to match and I haven't found out how to deal with that aspect.

I got help previously on a somewhat related problem where I was looking for a count instead of an average but couldn't figure out how to modify it to work for this one. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925742/vlookup-and-count-string-occurrences-in-separate-table-r-to-new-column/59925806?noredirect=1#comment106009474_59925806) for count issue looked like this:

```
df2 %>% 
right_join(df1, by = c('Winner' = 'School')) %>% 
na.omit() %>% 
count(Winner, name = "wins") %>% 
right_join(df1, c('Winner' = 'School')) %>% 
mutate(wins = replace(wins, is.na(wins), 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can join `classA` with `scores` and then take `mean` of `Away.Score` for each `School`.

```
library(dplyr)

classA %>% 
  left_join(scores, by = c('School' = 'Away.Team')) %>%
  group_by(School) %>%
  summarise(AwayScore = mean(Away.Score, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  School        AwayScore
#  <fct>             <dbl>
#1 Elkhorn              60
#2 Millard North        84
#3 Omaha South          60
```

Similarly in base R

```
aggregate(Away.Score~School, 
      merge(classA, scores, by.x = 'School', by.y = 'Away.Team'),
      mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: If I have other columns already in classA, is there a way to execute this without deleting them?

Comment: @JeffSwanson you can use `mutate` instead of `summarise` in last line.

Comment: thank you, but mutate seems to be adding a bunch of additional columns and rows from the `scores` dataframe and I just need the one new column to appear.

Comment: @JeffSwanson which column? Use that in `group_by` then. `group_by(School, other_column)`.

Comment: So, ultimately I need one new column in my main dataframe, classA. The new column should show an average of scores for each team. When I use `summarise`, the df is completely replaced with team names and averages only. I want to maintain existing columns in classA and just add the new column. I tried using `mutate` instead but that basically merged both data frames together somehow and was not the correct result. I don't think `group_by` will solve this. Sorry, don't think my explanation was very clear the last time.

Comment: @JeffSwanson Try `scores %>%
  group_by(Away.Team) %>%
  summarise(AwayScore = mean(Away.Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  right_join(classA, by = c('Away.Team' = 'School'))`